# Remove .html from URL using .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Recently we moved wordpress website into html, I like to have old url like wordpress. I was using following code, Its removing .html like `www.example.com/about-us` but image, css, js not loading, only text are coming. In console it shows url like `www.example.com/about-us/assests/css/style.css` instead of `www.example.com/assests/css/style.css`, page name automattically added middle of all source links.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

There is any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I think this is the only rule you need.

This is going to allow you access urls like `https://www.my-site.com/page.html` as `https://www.my-site.com/page`

Comment: Throws Server Error 403 Forbidden

Comment: This is a different error and I don't think is related to the rewrite directive :/

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```